# How find excel.exe path and notpad.exe path

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv, exe

In my application after `export excel or csv file` then show the file in excel or notepad.
In this case am use

Excel:

```
  Dim xExcelFilePath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\Microsoft Office"
            xDir = New DirectoryInfo(xExcelFilePath)
            For Each xDirectory As DirectoryInfo In xDir.GetDirectories ' it use for find any version of excel is installed or not
                If xDirectory.Name.Count < 6 Then Continue For
                If xDirectory.Name.Trim.Substring(0, 6).ToUpper = "OFFICE" Then
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(xExcelFilePath & "\" & xDirectory.Name & "\EXCEL.EXE") Then
                        xExcelFilePath = xExcelFilePath & "\" & xDirectory.Name & "\EXCEL.EXE"
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If System.IO.File.Exists(xExcelFilePath) Then
                Dim p As New Process() ' xExcelFilePath means start and stop the local system process
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
                p.StartInfo.FileName = xExcelFilePath ' Assaign the file name
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = """" + xDestinationPath + """"
                Grid1.SaveExcel(xDestinationPath, FarPoint.Win.Spread.Model.IncludeHeaders.ColumnHeadersCustomOnly) ' Export the Excel File
                p.Start()

            Else
                Msg.Err("Could not find Excel installed on this system; file saved to:" + xExcelFilePath + ".")
            End If
```

Notepad:

```
 Dim p As New Process() ' xExcelFilePath means start and stop the local system process
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\windows\notepad.exe"
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = """" + Application.StartupPath & Grid1.ActiveSheet.SheetName & ".csv" + """"
            xCSVSheet.SaveTextFile(Application.StartupPath & Grid1.ActiveSheet.SheetName & ".csv", TextFileFlags.None, Model.IncludeHeaders.BothCustomOnly, "", ",", "")
            p.Start()
```

In above code in some system `excel file` path not in this order so its throw exception and `Notepad exe` is staticly added here. How can i get the `exe file` path in sysem?

Comment: I suspected you would use the registry, so I googled it, and got this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240794

Comment: @Gray i have doubt. That is the big process?

Comment: Yes, the code there would work, but I think Nicholas Post's post is probably the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the exact path, let Windows handle that. If you want to open a file with Notepad, simply use the following code:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", Application.StartupPath & Grid1.ActiveSheet.SheetName & ".csv")
```

To start the program maximized, you would have to change it to something like this:

```
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
    startInfo.Arguments = """" & Application.StartupPath & Grid1.ActiveSheet.SheetName & ".csv"""
    Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Comment: if i using like this in excel its not correctly open. it show the file path not corrected.

Comment: If your path has spaces in it, you will need to pass a quote before and after. I updated the code to reflect this as well as tested it locally. Without the quotes it supplies the error you stated, and with them it works properly.

Comment: Put `MsgBox("""" & Application.StartupPath & Grid1.ActiveSheet.SheetName & ".csv""")` right before you call `Process.Start(startInfo)` and post the path. This code works fine on my machines, so I'm guessing that your path may be incorrect when you attempt to load the file in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Dim excelpath = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe", "Path", "Key does not exist")
                  excelpath=  excelpath & "EXCEL.EXE" 
     Shell(Chr(34) & excelpath & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & FLE & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
```

where in my case FLE is the XML file